# How to stop and start a Thread with new configuration?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

My program is whenever i start my AccelSender program, it sends epnId to my server machine to request host for that particular epnId. When the server returns hostName, it starts two Runnable Thread class called `new DataTransmitter(hostName,epnId)` and new `JMSConnection()`.

What i am trying to do is whenever my `reStart(String hostName)` is invoked i want to stop the `new DataTransmitter(hostName,epnId)` thread and start it with setting new hostName.

Here is my code:

```
public class AccelSender {

        private Socket kkSocket = null;
        private PrintWriter out = null;
        private BufferedReader in = null;

        private static final String epnId = "EPN1";

        public AccelSender(){
        }

        public void requestHost(){

            try{
                Socket hostSocket = new Socket("10.3.2.227",1121);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(hostSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(hostSocket.getInputStream()));
                out.println(epnId);
                    while(true){
                        String hostName = in.readLine();
                        DataTransmitter dt = new DataTransmitter(hostName,epnId);
                        JMSConnection jms = new JMSConnection();
                        new Thread(dt).start();
                        new Thread(jms).start();
                    }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    public void reStart(String hostName){
    //Here i want to STOP the DataTransmitter Thread and,
 START with new hostName
        }

    }
```

Code for Runnable class:

```
public class DataTransmitter implements Runnable {

    private Socket kkSocket = null;
    private PrintWriter out = null;
    private BufferedReader in = null;

    private int port = 2508, fileCount = 0, arrivalRate = 500;
    private String hostName = null, data = null, filename = null;
    private boolean resetSender = false;
    private static String epnId = null;
    File folder = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/input_data");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    public DataTransmitter(){
    }


    public DataTransmitter(String hostName, String epnId){

        this.hostName = hostName;
        this.epnId = epnId;
        establishHostConnection();
    }

    public void establishHostConnection(){

        try {
            kkSocket = new Socket(hostName, port);
            out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
            resetSender = true;
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: thinklatch.");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: 
thinklatch.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void close() throws IOException{

        kkSocket.close();
        out.close();
        in.close();
    }

    public void run(){

        System.out.println("Entering Data Transmitter");

        try{
            while (fileCount <= 1) {


                for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                        System.out.println("File " + 
listOfFiles[i].getName());
                        filename = System.getProperty("user.dir") + 
"/input_data/" + listOfFiles[i].getName();

                        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new 
FileReader(filename));
                        System.out.println("Fetching input from : " + 
filename);

                        while((data=bf.readLine())!=null){
                            String str = 
this.hostName+","+this.epnId+","+arrivalRate+","+data;
                            out.println(str);
                            try{
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(2);
                            }catch(Exception e){
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                     fileCount++;
            }
        }catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
            System.err.println("E"+fnfe);
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.err.println("E"+ioe);
        }
            out.close();
    }
}
```

Any advice on restarting the thread for this case is appreciable.
Thanks in advance ....

Comment: Might want to take a look at the related Questions. [how-to-start-stop-restart-a-thread-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881714/how-to-start-stop-restart-a-thread-in-java?rq=1) and [how-to-restart-thread-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468266/how-to-restart-thread-in-java?rq=1)

Comment: (somewhat off-topic) - you should follow Java conventions, and make all your class-names start with upper-case

Comment: Can you show the code of the `Runnable`?

Comment: Could you not give the data transmitter thread instance updated config rather than stop/start? Also once you kill a thread it's dead and not restartable. You will be starting a new thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A thread can't actually be "restarted" once the `run` method has finished executing. You have two options basically:

1. Introduce a loop that causes the thread to be suspended (e.g. call a `wait`) when a condition is met. That way you can "pause" the thread, change the hostname and then signal it to resume.
2. Cause the thread to finish its code, discard it and then start a new thread with the same `Runnable` object.

**Edit**: So what you can do in the restart method is to call to `close` method on the `dt` object. This will close the sockets and cause an `IOException` that will make the thread exit its run method. After that you can just start a new thread:

```
dt = new DataTransmitter(hostName,epnId);
new Thread(dt).start();
```

Comment: Inside my run() i am having endless loop which transmits data... How can i stop that...

Comment: @Vinesh: What if the old thread is still executing code when you want to restart it? Do you want to forcibly kill it?

Comment: What i am trying is stop data transfer to the current host & set new host and start data transfer...

Answer (score 1):

Use Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() and Thread.interrupt()

See this link :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Comment: (And then, after interrupting the thread, just launch a new one; you cannot restart a thread, but you can start a new one)

Answer (score 0):

`Thread` once stopped `can't be restarted`.

**-** Once the thread of Execution associated with the Thread Class Instance finishes its `run()` method, it moves into the `Dead State`, or `Thread Pool` if implemented. The Thread Class Instance which was associated with the thread of Execution Permanently looses its Threadness.

**-** You can better use the `wait()` and `notify()` mechanism, and can also use `await()` and `signal()` mechanism from java.util.concurrent package, to suspend and resume the thread.

Comment: "The Instance Thread Class Instance which was associated with the thread of Execution Permanently looses its Threadness" ?

Comment: Oh don't don't don't use wait() and notify(). You should consider these "deprecated" (cf. Effective Java by Joshua Bloch)

Comment: @BrianAgnew thanks for showing the `typo`..and @SteveMcLeod thats the reason i mentioned the `await() and signal() methods.`